# Can we programmatically determine Custom Metadata Type picklist values?

Tags: apex, picklist, custom-metadata

I would like to create a Custom Metadata Type picklist, and I want the values of the picklist to programmatically display the names of user Roles in the org. So if someone adds a new user Role, the picklist values should automatically show it. Pretty basic for regular picklist fields in VF, but can we do this with Custom Metadata Types? Appreciate any ideas on where to start.

Comment: Take a look at this [Custom Metadata Services GitHub repo](https://github.com/afawcett/custommetadataapi)